# How can you simply select consecutive variables by name, as with the : operator in SAS?

Tags: r

If you are familiar with SAS, you know how the ":" operator works.

For example, I have a table (Table1) for which the column names are like this:
**Surface Circle Area1 Area2 Area3 ... Area12**

I can call the **Area1 Area2 ... Area12** columns like this:

```
data Table2;
set Table1;
keep Area:;
run;
```

What is the equivalent of this in R ?

Imagine the following dataset:

```
a1 = 1:10
a2 = 11:20
a3 = 21:30
a4 = 31:40
b = 50:59
df = data.frame(a1, a2, a3, a4, b)
```

How can I select the columns a1 ... a4 with  a command as simple as the one we use in SAS?

Comment: Please change your title to a meaningful summary of your question.

Comment: You can select columns using tidyverse functions like starts_with(). You can create a character vector using grepl(), then use that vector to subset in bracket notation (e.g. df[, selectedCols])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
table <- input_table %>% 
select(num_range("a", 1:4))
```

I am free to choose any combinations of a1 a2 ... I want.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you are asking, your are looking for something like this (which makes use of `dplyr` package):

`df %>% select(a1:a4)`

Edit:
If instead you are looking for a way to *select all columns which start with the pattern 'a'*, you need the `starts_with` helper:

`df %>% select(starts_with("a"))`

[Link to the documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)

Comment: Nice answer - it looks like dplyr already incorporates this syntax!

Comment: I see, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can select consecutive column in base R with `subset`:

```
subset(df, select = a1:a4)
```

If you want to select columns off of how they start, in base R we could approach it like this:

```
df[names(df) |> startsWith("a")]
```

Comment: Does that mean variables with the names a1,a2,a3,a4 like the SAS syntax of a1-a4.  Or the variables in position order from a1 to a4 like the SAS syntax of a1--a4? Either way it doesn't seem address the question of how to select variables with names that start with the letter a.

Comment: This selects the consecutive variables in column order, starting with `a1` to `a4`, answering OP's stated question of *"How can I select the columns a1 ... a4?"*, and what is stated in the question title *"select consecutive variables by name"*. If they want to select based on the start of the name, I'd encourage OP to edit the question to state that clearly. I've edited my answer to add a "starts with" method.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, that is a pretty good answer. But, what if I do not know when "a1" "a2" ..."an" ends? In other words, I want all consecutive columns of "a1" "a2" ... and I do not know what is the last number "an" ? can you do it using subset function?

Comment: No, you can't. You can either use the second approach proposed by @GregorThomas or consider using dplyr and its helpers (please read the documentation in this case), see my answer